# ALSA's snd_pcm_get_chmap always returns NULL on my default device (pulse) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, audio, ubuntu-18.04, alsa, pulseaudio

I'm successfully rendering audio with alsa, however I'm completely incapable of determining the channel mapping. As various sources have stated, I'm calling `snd_pcm_get_chmap` after the hw & sw params are set and the device is prepared.

`snd_config_get_string` returns 'pulse' for this device which I'm presuming means it's an alsa/pulseaudio bridge for want of a better term.

Calling `snd_strerror(errno)` after `snd_pcm_get_chmap` fails is returning 'Socket operation on non-socket'. I should probably add that I'm debugging remotely from Visual Studio 2017 as that may be related.

I'd really like to be able to get the channel mapping. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to mention, `snd_pcm_query_chmaps` also returns NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Pulse audio's list of ALSA issues states that it isn't currently possible to obtain the channel map. https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Backends/ALSA/Issues/

> There's no way to query the active channel map for a device

Comment: Consolidating comments I made here:
1. Coming late to this question but I wonder if the pulse audio guys have seen this: https://docs.kernel.org/sound/designs/channel-mapping-api.html -- seems this documentation was introduced to the Linux kernel tree in 2012. 
2. Following up, I did find some alsa lib code that seems to retrieve the map from the ctl interface. Maybe actual implementation differs by kernel driver. https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-lib/blob/7f2d6c3aac3505ceee4b0d3e8b3ca423ce29b070/src/pcm/pcm_hw.c#L1320
3. I was indeed able to query the channel map on my own machine.